# My simple array program not giving the expected output

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I wrote a simple array which I store 3x3 matrix. But when I run the code it doesn't give 3x3 matrix. just gives a single column as output.

```
class sucks
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int g[][]=new int[3][3];

        int h,k,l=0;

        for(k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            for(h=0;h<3;h++)
            {

                g[k][h]=l;
                l++;

            }
        }

        for(k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            for(h=0;h<3;h++)
            {

                System.out.print(g[k][h]+" ");
                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The out put is like this

0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

Comment: Where is the logic in your code that you would expect to print it in a 3x3 arrangement?

Comment: There is no "matrix" in the memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just print a new line for each row. Like this :

```
for(k=0;k<3;k++){
    for(h=0;h<3;h++){    
       System.out.print(g[k][h]+" ");    
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

To improve your code, you could also change your for loops like this :

```
for(k=0;k<g.length;k++){
    for(h=0;h<g[k].length;h++){
```